# Best way for mapping non-sequential values in C

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, error-handling

I have a very contrived error code system (a few hundreds of non-sequential values, C language) with an equally contrived conversion to human-readable error messages.

I'm thinking about refactoring this, but I not sure of the best way of mapping a value to its corresponding string. Any tips?

The error codes are unique, and can't be used to compose new codes.

The error codes are built so that each code has a *base* value, specifying which module it belongs to. There are offsets for warnings and status messages:

```
#define SOME_MODULE_ERR_BASE    0x120000
#define OTHER_MODULE_ERR_BASE   0x130000

#define STATUS_OFFSET  1000
#define WARNING_OFFSET 2000

/* Error codes as defined as needed, sequentially from the base value */
#define SOME_MODULE_ERR_NOT_FOUND   (SOME_MODULE_ERR_BASE + 1)
#define SOME_MODULE_ERR_BAD_CRC     (SOME_MODULE_ERR_BASE + 2)
#define SOME_MODULE_STATUS_BUSY     (SOME_MODULE_ERR_BASE + STATUS_OFFSET + 1)
#define SOME_MODULE_WARNING_INCOMPLETE (SOME_MODULE_ERR_BASE + WARNING_OFFSET + 1)

#define OTHER_MODULE_ERR_BAD_CRC     (OTHER_MODULE_ERR_BASE + 1)
#define OTHER_MODULE_ERR_NOT_FOUND   (OTHER_MODULE_ERR_BASE + 2)
/*...*/
```

We currently have code to print the appropriate error string, but the process of conversion (from error code to string) is so bizarre that even adding new error codes is a chore. I want to improve our logging system, but this stupid code is getting in the way. By refactoring the error message printing I will be able to refactor the logging system.

Basically, I want this:

```
result = SomeModuleFunc();
printf("SomeModuleFunc returned %s\n", ErrToString(result));
```

And it would print `SOME_MODULE_ERR_NOT_FOUND`, `SOME_MODULE_ERR_BAD_CRC`, `SOME_MODULE_STATUS_BUSY`, etc as appropriate.

Seems to me that the simplest approach would be just to build a giant switch-case statement pointing to the appropriate string, but maybe it's just because I can't think of a good data structure to simplify the mapping process.

Comment: A binary search tree of key-value pairs will do.

Comment: Is error-reporting performance important? I think some switch-case implementations will build a jump table for you, and shorten the code by testing in a loop rather than inline.

Comment: Error codes are just integers? Like `enum errors_e { ERROR_1 = 123, ERROR_2 = 43, ERROR_3 = 103958, }`? Are there any sequences? Like `enum { ERROR_X_1 = 1, ERROR_X_2, ERROR_X_3, ERROR_Y_1 =100, ERROR_Y_2 , ERROR_Y_3 }` ? Can error codes be composed of multiple errors? like `return ERROR_X_3 | ERROR_Y_1` ?

Comment: Variant of @EugeneSh.'s proposition: You can do a binary search on an array containing pairs of error codes and corresponding string values.

Comment: Just because the error values are non-sequential does not mean you cannot use a simple table with a direct code-to-index correspondence.  It's ok if some of the entries have no message.  The main potential issue here is if you have *large* gaps between error numbers, so that the table wastes a lot of space.

Comment: Possibly faster than binary search might be a hash table. You might want to have a look at [gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) that might create a close to optimum hash function for your values.

Comment: Show some code demonstrating what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the error codes are HUGE or if you have very limited resources, my solution would be to just have a big array of char pointers to the messages.

```
const char *error_msg[] = {
    "", "", "Out of memory", "", "Out of disk space", 
    "", "", "", "Unauthorized user" ... 
};
```

It's simple and it works. If the highest code is very high, which it seems to be in your case, you might get problems. In that case, use a pointer to pointer.

```
const char **error_msg;

void init_error() 
{
    error_msg = calloc(size, sizeof(*error_msg));
    error_msg[2] = "Out of memory";
    error_msg[4] = "Out of disk space";
    error_msg[8] = "Unauthorized user";
}
```

With the latter approach, you cannot do the initialization in global space, so use an init function and call it in the beginning of `main`. But for both you can use this function, as long as `error_msg` is global.

```
const char *ErrToString(size_t code) 
{ 
    return error_msg[code]; 
}
```

Sure, this approach wastes memory, but unless you have very limited resources, that's not an issue. The base number `0x130000` is around 1.2 millions in decimal. So if the pointers are 8 bytes, this will be below 10MB, which is nothing on a modern computer. And it's definitely much faster than any hashing or binary search. Usually, performance of generating error messages is not the biggest problem when you have to generate an error message, but in case you care about that it could be worth knowing.

Pros:

- Extremely simple to implement
- Lighting fast

Cons:

- Wastes memory

Simple is often best. Don't complicate things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of hash-table.
If your errcode-set is fixed, you can choose some "magic divider", and divide error codes to it, and use reminder as index in the array, for instance:

```
const char *p_msg = err_msg_arr[err_code % MAGIC];
```

Of course, your array must have size [MAGIC];

To find out this magic value, just write a simple program, which has list of the codes, and try incremental candidates for MAGIC, until found a set of unique remains.

Example of such program and input data file:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

my %in_set;

while(<>) {
  chomp;
  my ($errcode, $str) = m/(\d+)\s+(.+)/;
  $in_set{$errcode} = $str;
  #  print STDERR "added: [$errcode] => [$str]\n";
}

my $size = scalar keys %in_set;

my @rems;
for(my $magic = $size; $magic < $size * 10; $magic++) {
  @rems = (-1)x$magic;
  foreach (keys %in_set) {
    my $rem = $_ % $magic;
    goto NXT if $rems[$rem] >= 0;
    $rems[$rem] = $_;
  }
  # found the unque set of remains
  print "const char *err_msg[$magic] = {\n";
  for(my $m = 0; $m < $magic; $m++) {
    print $rems[$m] < 0? "\tNULL,\n" : "\t\"$in_set{$rems[$m]}\",\n";
  }
  exit;
  NXT:
} # for magic
```

Data file:

```
$ cat err_samples.txt 
100 error num 1
250 err 2
5000 err #1
```

Run result:

```
 ./errgen.pl err_samples.txt 
const char *err_msg[8] = {
    "err #1",
    NULL,
    "err 2",
    NULL,
    "error num 1",
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
```

Comment: And very often your `MAGIC` number ends up being `(max_error_code+1)`, at which point you're back where you started.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to handle this is to create a struct containing the error code and the error message, then create an array containing each code/message with the error codes in increasing numerical order:

```
struct error_codes {
    int code;
    const char *message;
};

struct error_codes codes[] = {
    { 4, "file not found" },
    { 10, "out of memory" },
    { 12, "can't connect" },
    ...
};
```

Then create a function that does a binary search of the list for the given error code:

```
const char *error_message(int code)
{
    int len = sizeof(codes) / sizeof(codes[0]);
    int start = 0, end = len - 1;

    while (start <= end) {
        int idx = start + ((end - start) / 2);

        if (codes[idx].code < code) {
            end = idx - 1;
        } else if (codes[idx].code > code) {
            start = idx + 1;
        } else {
            return codes[idx].message;
        }
    }
    return "unknown error code";            
}
```

With a few hundred error codes, this won't take more than 10 iterations.

If the total number of messages is somewhat close to the maximum value and all values are nonnegative, you can just create an array of strings with its index being the error code, and putting in a dummy value for unused error codes.  However, given the high error code bases you have that would mean a very large array which isn't feasible.

Comment: Why would you write your own binary search when you can call [bsearch()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_bsearch)?

Comment: Worth specifically noting that the list should be sorted by the numerical value.